# How to make org-mode use bibulous.py instead of biber?

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode, bibliography

I would like to export my Org documents to a PDF and have `bibulous.py` format the bibliography. For this I use the command `C-c C-e l p` aka `org-latex-pdf-process`.  Here is how I have adapted the command to my needs

```lisp
    (setq org-latex-pdf-process
          (list "lualatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode %f"
            (concat "python C:/pythonpath/bibulous.py " "my_document_name" ".aux")
            "lualatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode %f"
            "lualatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode %f"))
```

This works so far, but only for my test document with the name `my_document_name`. To keep things general, there should be a function here that uses the current buffer name. I tried

```
    python C:/pythonpath/bibulous.py %f.aux
```

but it does not work. I suspect that the variable `%f` contains the extension `.tex` (is there a way to see what exactly was called? the `*Messages*` buffer does not show this).

I have also tried the following

```lisp
    (concat "python C:/pythonpath/bibulous.py " (file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name) ".aux")
```

however, it seems that this variable is set when Emacs is launched, and does not access the actual buffer name during runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the doc of `org-latex-pdf-process` by `C-h v org-latex-pdf-process`

```
Commands to process a LaTeX file to a PDF file.

This is a list of strings, each of them will be given to the
shell as a command.  %f in the command will be replaced by the
relative file name, %F by the absolute file name, %b by the file
base name (i.e. without directory and extension parts), %o by the
base directory of the file, %O by the absolute file name of the
output file, %latex is the LaTeX compiler (see
org-latex-compiler), and %bib is the BibTeX-like compiler (see
org-latex-bib-compiler).

...
```

So all you need is

```lisp
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
      '("lualatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode %f"
        "python C:/pythonpath/bibulous.py %b.aux"
        "lualatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode %f"
        "lualatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode %f"))
```